# copy tables from Prod to Test in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I have 2 tables in my Prod that have about 1M records each i need to copy just these two tables to my test environment and while doing that i need to able to delete the records from a particular date range. Can i set up a JOB to do it or any other process because i need to do it every month. I am using Import\Export for now. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Linked Server:

```
INSERT INTO db_name.schema.table_name(col1, col2, ...)
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM prd_linked_server.db_name.schema.table_name
WHERE date_column BETWEEN ... AND ...;  -- some expressions that calculate range
```

Also there is no need for deleting anything, just select required subset of data. As a final step, set SQL Server Agent Job and schedule it to run every month.

---

**EDIT:**

Instead of Linked Server you could save Import/Export Wizard as SSIS package and schedule it.

**[Save SSIS Package (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/save-ssis-package-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard)**

**[How to: Automate SSIS Package Execution by Using the SQL Server Agent](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440761(v=sql.100).aspx)**

Still you don't to move entire table, in source instead of selecting table, use custom query.

Comment: i dont have a linked server setup , is there any other way, thanks

Comment: Can you use SSIS or Powerwhell ?

Comment: got it . will i be able to include a query into it to delete the old records ? thanks

Comment: You can do anything with those 2